# Passing bearer token using javascript in Swagge rUI

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, bearer-token

We are using Swagger to implement documentation for our APIs.  Our APIs use OpenId Connect (authorization code flow) for authorization. We are in the process of developing a website that can be used by our customers to try out the APIS.

The website also uses  OpenId Connect(authorization code flow) for authorization.So we want to reuse the bearer token that is generated during the web site login with Swagger UI rather than the user having to click on the "Authorize" button to authorize.

Is it possible to pass the bearer-token as header in SwaggerUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one is interested, the answer can be found on

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3795#issuecomment-338331557